# Can you call an IIFE after it has need invoked already without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to call a IIFE function again without reloading the page? Similar to the way you call a regular function.

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? More context would be helpful.

Comment: An IIFE is when a function literal directly forms the function part of a call expression. It can still be a named function expression, e.g. `(function foo() { setTimeout(foo, 1000); )()`. This question doesn’t make much sense without the context of a specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not unless the IIFE itself is inside a function, and you trigger that function itself again, eg

```
const fn = () => {
  (() => {
    // do stuff
  })();
};
fn();
fn();
```

Which is weird.

If you want to be able to call something more than once, you should put into a variable so it can be referenced again - a regular named function

```
const fn = () => {
  // do stuff
};
fn();
fn();
```

An IIFE is *designed* to be the sort of thing that (usually) runs exactly once. If you want to run something multiple times, an IIFE is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks for the info and good point!

If I wanted to have a function (no IIFE) run on window load, do you think it would be efficient to remove the IIFE, create an function expression and then put that inside window.load?

That way it would allow me to have the function run on load and also allow me to call it afterwards?

Not even sure that would work...

Comment: Sure, that's completely normal, though it's not really something to do with efficiency, just code organization.